# Creating PHP login system

Tags: php

I'm building a login system with PHP and I can't figure out why my code isn't working. When I submit the login form, the page just refreshes and nothing happens. Can someone help me find the error in my code?

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['loginbtn'])){
require_once 'index.php';
require_once 'Database_conx.php';

$emailbox = $_POST ["loginemailbox"];
$loginpasswordbox = $_POST ["loginpasswordbox"];
$loginpasswordbox = md5($loginpasswordbox);

$result = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT * FROM Registration where Email = "'.$emailbox.'" and User_Password= "'.$loginpasswordbox.'" ');

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
    $_SESSION['loginemailbox'] = $emailbox;
    header('Location:home.php');
}
 }
 ?>
```

And here's my HTML code, which is located in my index.php file:

```
<div id="header_top_password">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password" name="loginpasswordbox" style="border :0px">
</div>

<div id="loginbutton">
    <button type="submit" name="loginbtn" class="btn btn-danger pull-right">Login</button>
</div>

<div id="forget_Password">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Forget your Password?</button>
</div>
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: can you post the error message?

Comment: You tell us __ERROR__ and we __PROVIDE__ you solution!!

Comment: well `name attribute` missing in `button type`

Comment: it's not the login button.. it's the forgot password btn.. he was using `anchor`

Comment: missed `double quote` after `$loginpasswordbox.'" '`. it should be `$loginpasswordbox.'" ' "`.

Comment: Instead of anchor tag use submit button for login.

Comment: @saty is right. And don't check form submit button. Test username and password inputs always.

Comment: Base on @Saty 's answer, your submit button shoud be `<input type="submit" name="loginbtn" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" value="Login" />`

Comment: you should add else condition so that you can trace til where your code is raching

Comment: thanks for the help guys . when i run the code it display's a blank page in the  browser

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Please read [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for information on how to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

For Submit button Use input instead of a tag.
For example:

```
 <form action="demo_form.php">
   Username: <input type="text" name="usrname"><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

Answer (score -1):

i think you should replace this two line in login.php.

```
$emailbox         = $_POST ["loginemailbox"];
$loginpasswordbox = $_POST ["loginpasswordbox"];
```

with this.

```
$emailbox         = $_POST["loginemailbox"];
$loginpasswordbox = $_POST["loginpasswordbox"];
```

remove blank space.